# Indicator function and $\liminf$

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$. Prove that 
$$
\liminf_n A_n =\{\omega: \lim_{n} 1_{A_n}(\omega)=1\}=\left\{ \omega: \sum_{n }1_{A_n^c}(\omega) <\infty \right\}.
$$

*Solution:*

My attempt is the following:

\begin{align*}
\omega \in \liminf_n A_n &\iff \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad \forall k_n \ge n, \quad \omega \in A_{k_n} \\ 
&\iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad \exists k_n, n> k_n, \quad \omega \notin A_{k_n} \\ 
& \iff  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad \exists k_n, n> k_n, \quad \omega \in A_{k_n}^c \\ 
& \iff  \omega \in \left\{ \omega: \sum_{n }1_{A_n^c}(\omega) <\infty \right\}.
\end{align*}

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What is your exact definition of $\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n$?

Comment: The traditional i.e. $$ \liminf_{n \to \infty}A_n:=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{k \ge n}A_k $$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping me out. I think I wrote down a similar argument with symbols.

Well, if $\omega \in \{\omega: \sum_{n}1_{A_n^c}(\omega)<\infty\}$, then for there exists $n \in\mathbb{N} $, for all $k \ge n$ such that $\omega \in A_k$ which is exactly $\omega \in \liminf_{n}A_n$. In particular, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $1_{A_k}(\omega)=1$ for all $k \ge n$ i.e. $\lim_n 1_{A_n}(\omega)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega\in\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n$. Then there exists $n$ such that $\omega\in A_k$ for $k\geqslant n$. From this it follows immediately that $\omega\in\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathsf 1_{A_n}(\omega)$. Moreover, since $\omega\in A_n$ for infinitely many $n$, the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf 1_{A_n^c}(\omega)$ converges.

Can you find the converse argument from there?